# Article use with nouns

Tags: articles

In “Objective IELTS” by M. Black (Teacher’s book) the word sales is used without articles, e.g.:
“In the first quarter, sales of the new “Flying Boots” were …” “… while sales of “Zed Runners”…” et c. (from a sample essay on trainers sales).
Is it wrong?

Comment: It's just the generic use of "sales" rather then the definite use.

Comment: No worse than "cats are mammals" -- the determiner 'all' is implied.  All sales of ...  ('all' is a *definite* quantifier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all nouns require articles in English. Specifically, when one is referring to a class of things (in this example, sales) no article is required; the noun is being used as though it were a mass (uncountable; non-count) noun. To the extent that there's an implicit quantifier, it's context-dependent but usually one of "all", "most", or a specifier such as "the relevant".

Comment: So, the use of the definite article in this case would be a mistake, wouldn't it?

Comment: It would, yes. At least, it works be a mistake to attach it to "sales". The example uses the definite article in 'the new "Flying Boots"', and that's fine, of course.